# How would I automatically apply this JavaScript bookmarklet script to every website I visit (until deactivated)?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I found a neat JavaScript "bookmarklet" (i.e some javascript code that I can activate by clicking a link on my bookmarks tab in Chrome/FF):

```
javascript:(function(){var newSS, styles='* { background: black ! important; color: grey !important } :link, :link * { color: #0000EE%20!important%20}%20:visited,%20:visited%20*%20{%20color:%20#551A8B%20!important%20}';%20if(document.createStyleSheet)%20{%20document.createStyleSheet("javascript:'"+styles+"'");%20}%20else%20{%20newSS=document.createElement('link');%20newSS.rel='stylesheet';%20newSS.href='data:text/css,'+escape(styles);%20document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newSS);%20}%20})();
```

The issue is that, when I'm browsing a forum or a tutorial,  I ahve to keep clicking the "Darken" button . Is it possible to apply it permanently(i.e, a la CSS script ) ?

Thank you much!

Answer (score 1):

Bookmarklets can only be run when user initiated. For something that would run automatically on pages, you'd have to look into plugins.

You can look at [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for FF or [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo/details?hl=en) for Chrome. Otherwise, you can write your own plugin/extension. :)

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll look into Tampermonkey, sounds neat

Comment: @Caffeinated how you did it with tampermonkey?

Answer (score 1):

I found a more permanent solution via a useful Chrome add-in called "Deluminate" - it's one solution !

[Extension Deluminate Link -](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/deluminate/iebboopaeangfpceklajfohhbpkkfiaa?hl=en-US)